# PyQt5 Sidebar Widget Not Collapsing as Expected

Tags: python, pyqt, sidebar, qwidget

I'm developing a **PyQt5 application** that incorporates a sidebar widget for displaying various types of information. The sidebar is implemented using `QDockWidget` and `QStackedLayout`. I want this sidebar to be **collapsible**, but it's not behaving as intended.

Here's the relevant code for creating the sidebar:

```
class Sidebar(QDockWidget):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
        
# Create a QStackedLayout for the contents of the dock widget
self.layout = QStackedLayout()

# Various sections
self.alerts_list = QListWidget()
self.layout.addWidget(self.alerts_list)

# More widgets added to the layout...

# Create a QWidget to hold the layout
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(self.layout)

# Set the dock widget's widget to the layout widget
self.setWidget(widget)
```

I add this sidebar to my `QMainWindow` as follows:

```
self.sidebar = Sidebar()
self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.sidebar)
```

The sidebar appears on the interface as expected. However, it doesn't collapse when I click on it. I have tried employing `QGroupBox` and `QSplitter` in my attempts to make the sidebar collapsible, but to no avail.

When I run the program, I receive the error:

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget ""

which already has a layout. I believe this could be related to my issue, but I'm not certain how to resolve it.

Could anyone provide some guidance on how to make the sidebar collapsible? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: "it doesn't collapse when I click on it" why should it collapse? Did you attempt to implement that behavior? And what do you mean by "collapsible"? Should it hide completely or should it have a smaller size? Please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: I also can't understand 'collapsible sidebar'. Normally we say a ```QDockWidget``` collapses(disappears) when you click the 'x' button of it. You mean it? Then post a [mre]. The posted code does not show anything that can possibly disable that behavior.